Detect which client Id / gateway was used for GooglePay
A partner of us operates multiple apps and processes Google Pay in those. There are some legacy apps which are hard to update and also some legacy websites using the Google Pay Javascript SDK.
In those websites the partner initializes the SDK with the information provided by the PSP. Following two options are used:
Adyen:
"tokenizationSpecification": {
  "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
  "parameters": {
    "gateway": "adyen",
    "gatewayMerchantId": "YOUR_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_NAME"
  }
}

Chase:
"tokenizationSpecification": {
  "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
  "parameters": {
    "gateway": "chase",
    "gatewayMerchantId": "YOUR_GATEWAY_MERCHANT_ID"
  }
}

The partner then sends us the payload and we receive following:
{
  "encryptedPayload": "{\"encryptedMessage\":\"dDkzUfxxxxxW/8K8\"}",
  "encryptedPaymentHeader": {
    "ephemeralPublicKey": "BCxxxx="
  },
  "signature": "MEQCIQxxxxGQbxi7rJA==",
  "protocolVersion": "ECv1"
}

Is there a way to detect which config was used?
What we have tried:

We tried to find any parameter which stays static
We tried to decode the payload


Unfortunately the token does not contain a gateway identifier. You would need to change your own API and ask the partner to send such an identifier.

ok thanks! then we might try first always with the preferred provider

The Google Pay payment method token does not contain a gateway identifier.
